# Opencv convolution matrix gives unusual results

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, filter, convolution

So I have a program that is trying to apply a simple 3x3 convolution matrix to an image.

This is the function that is doing the work:

```
Mat process(Mat image) {

    int x = 2;
    int y = 2;
    Mat nimage(image); //just a new mat to put the resulting image on

    while (y < image.rows-2) {

        while (x < image.cols-2) {

            nimage.at<uchar>(y,x) = //apply matrix to pixel
            image.at<char>(y-1,x-1)*matrix[0]+
            image.at<char>(y-1,x)*matrix[1]+
            image.at<char>(y-1,x+1)*matrix[2]+
            image.at<char>(y,x-1)*matrix[3]+
            image.at<char>(y,x)*matrix[4]+
            image.at<char>(y,x+1)*matrix[5]+
            image.at<char>(y+1,x-1)*matrix[6]+
            image.at<char>(y+1,x)*matrix[7]+
            image.at<char>(y+1,x+1)*matrix[8];

            //if (total < 0) total = 0;
            //if (total > 255) total = 255;

            //cout << (int)total << ": " << x << "," << y << endl;

            x++;
        }

        x = 0;
        y++;
    }

    cout << "done" << endl;

    return nimage;

}
```

And the matrix looks like this

```
double ar[9] = {-1,0,0,
                0,2,0,
                0,0,0};
```

And the image that is used as input looks like this:

[image]

The desired output (I ran the same matrix on the input image in GIMP):

[image]

And the result is... weird:

[image]

I think this has to do with the data type I use when I set a pixel of the new image (`nimage.at<uchar>(y,x) = ...`), because whenever I change it I get a different, yet still incorrect result.

Comment: Why don't you use standard convolution fonctions available in opencv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the OpenCV documentation about the copy constructor of `Mat`, emphasis mine:

> **m** – Array that (as a whole or partly) is assigned to the constructed matrix. No data is copied by these constructors. Instead, the header pointing to m data or its sub-array is constructed and associated with it. The reference counter, if any, is incremented. **So, when you modify the matrix formed using such a constructor, you also modify the corresponding elements of `m`. If you want to have an independent copy of the sub-array, use `Mat::clone()`.**

So

```
Mat nimage(image); //just a new mat to put the resulting image on
```

doesn't actually create a new matrix; it creates a new `Mat` object, but that object still refers to the same matrix. From then on `nimage.at(y,x)` acts like `image.at(y,x)`.

To copy the image, use

```
Mat nimage(image.clone()); //just a new mat to put the resulting image on
```

Comment: THANK. YOU. SO. MUCH. I hadn't even thought to look at that part of it. I'll try to look at the docs in more detail in the future :/